# The current npm install location requires admin privileges

Tags: npm, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to build my `cordova` app in visual studio 2015 and I'm getting this error

```
The current npm install location C:\Users\{users}\AppData\Roaming\npm requires admin privileges to install a package. To resolve the issue, either change the ACL for C:\Users\{users}\AppData\Roaming\npm or change the install path by running 'npm config set prefix %AppData%\npm' and restarting Visual Studio in order to build without being an admin.
```

its occurred when using windows 10

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on that directory to ensure you have write access?  Seems like it's a pretty easy fix to just change the permissions or point the NPM directory to something different where you do have access?

Comment: i also thought its easy to fix, and i gave the folder administrator privilege, still getting the error

Comment: And you've tried what the error message said?  To run `npm config set prefix %AppData%\npm` and that had no effect?

Comment: yes alos try this not working.